What's the difference between using subscription or resource group role IDs for the same role in Bicep?
Consider the Key Vault Secrets User Azure role.
I can refer to this role using either its subscription ID or its resource group ID within RBAC role assignments:
resource keyVaultRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(
    resourceGroup().id,
    resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6')
  )
  scope: keyVault
  properties: {
    principalId: appServiceApp.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6')
  }
}

What's the difference between using the subscription ID and the resource group ID?
Key Vault Secrets User Role IDs:
Subscription Role ID:
/subscriptions/ad47cf56-0e91-421b-9886-ea29cb833788/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6

Resource group Role ID:
/subscriptions/ad47cf56-0e91-421b-9886-ea29cb833788/resourceGroups/TodoAppTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6


if we re talking about built-in role this is the same as roles are inherited. Custom roles can be defined at different scope/level so that would make a difference. not sure if that make sense for you?

@Thomas No, that doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand why the same role exists, with different IDs, on several scope levels (e.g. subscription) in Azure. If there only was a single instance of a role, say on the tenant level, you could just assign that with e.g. a resource scope (scope: argument)

If I am not mistaken, it's the difference between assigning the role to all resources of that specific type inside of the subscription (using Subscription Role ID) or assigning the role to all resources of that specific type inside of the resource group (Resource group Role ID).
There is also a resource scope for role assignments in Azure. When you assign a role at the resource scope, the role assignment applies only to that specific resource. This provides the most granular level of access control.

The Azure RBAC model allows users to set permissions on different scope levels: management group, subscription, resource group, or individual resources. Azure RBAC for key vault also allows users to have separate permissions on individual keys, secrets, and certificates
For more information, see Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC).

Taken from Provide access to Key Vault keys, certificates, and secrets with an Azure role-based access control.

Thank you @rickvbosch. The scope: keyVault argument above sets the scope of the role assignment to a specific key vault. In any case, the role assignment doesn't show up under the subscription or resource group ID, but only on the key vault. So, in that case it seems there is no difference between using the subscription ID and the resource group ID

If an RBAC role assignment is always associated with a scope, why has Microsoft created the same role on different levels: management group, subscription, resource group? If there only was a single instance of a role, say on the tenant level, then you could just refer to that and specify the scope to be e.g. a subscription?

I don't understand the reasoning behind having the role, with different role IDs, on several levels? In AWS, you would assign the principal a role, but then scope it via conditions
